# override equals method in protobuf generated files in flutter

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers

I am using `protocol buffers` in `flutter`. I have several objects, one of them is:

```
message LogTag{
   string name = 1;
   int32 color = 2;
   int32 icon = 3; 
}
```

I have generated necessary dart files using `protoc compiler`. But, what I want is that its `equals` method should check `only` `name` field to compare 2 LogTag objects in my project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Altering the protoc-generated sources will potentially break the generated code's ability to (un)marshal the types into protobuf messages and is strongly discouraged.

If you wish to create user-defined methods that leverage the underlying (generated) types, you should create user-defined classes and convert these to|from the protoc-generated types.

Not only does this permit you to add arbitrary methods but the classes are less tightly-coupled.

Comment: in this case, is there a way to override comparable methods for methods like list.add, list.remove in Dart like in Java?